# Which should I use between $apply and $watch when working with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have just started working with AngularJS and getting my feet wet working with directives . These are fun!

I have a requirement to implement a text-area which accepts 10 characters , should accept only a-z A-Z 0-9 $ , ;  etc..

I have built two plunks,
one where the validate fires basing on scope and doing a $watch on the text
and the other where i fire the validation on key up event. I am using element.on('keyup') event and not ng-keyup.

So the question is which is a better approach and why so ? I would really appreciate a thought out answer :-)

Here are my plunks for your comments

1.http://plnkr.co/edit/5n8HBGVDnLcYcSI8DrbP

```
var ValidatorDirective = function() {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
    scope.charsleft = attributes.allowedlength;
    scope.$watch('text', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
      TextAreaWatcher(newVal, oldVal, scope, attributes);
    });
```

2.http://plnkr.co/edit/WCosbgFeQ6Ow8p2YI4q0

```
var ValidatorDirective = function() {


return {
  restrict: 'A',
  compile: function(element, attributes) {
    attributes.$set('ng-trim', false);
    return function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
      var maxAllowedLength = Number(attributes.allowedlength);
      var localModel = scope.data;
      localModel.charsleft = maxAllowedLength;
      element.on('keyup', function(keyEvent) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          var newVal = element.val();
          TextAreaWatcher(newVal, localModel, attributes);
        });
      });
    }
  },
  scope: {
    data: '=data'
  }
}
```

}

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very different

**$watch helps to listen for $scope changes that means** it will fire for every change in the model or expression (ex:- keyup, assignment in controller etc.)

element.on('keyup', function(keyEvent) is a jquery event so you need to manually apply digest cycle by $apply [tutorial](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

> $apply enables to integrate changes with the digest cycle

So,First one is more efficient in terms of capturing all the changes (But it will do dirty checking which may be costlier if you are doing it for single type of change.)